# Regex expression to remove whitespaces between {{ }}

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having issue building up the regex expression for the following problem :-

Here is my following code :-

```js
let modifiedData = ecData.info.slice(0, 1);
      let keys = Object.keys(modifiedData[0])
      this.previewData = this.htmlBody
      keys.forEach((key) => {
        this.previewData = this.previewData.replace(`{{${key}}}`, modifiedData[0][key]);
    });
```

Here what I am doing is rendering the html output in the modal.

Now say i have a object for example :-

let abc = { city: "mumbai", name: "ronak"};

Now my output is right when i am sending data like `<p>{{city}}</p>` so the rendered html is `mumbai` but when I am writing code like this `<p>{{ city }}</p>` so it is rendering the same output `<p>{{ city }}</p>` so I want a regex so that it can remove the start and end whitespaces including `{{ }}`, So how should I do it ?

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: why you want this?

Comment: Because I am replacing the Object keys with its values so if I write {{ city }} its not showing its value, but when I write {{city}} it gives me o/p as mumbai so I want to put a condition for this.

Comment: `"{{ asdf }}".replace(/{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}/g,"{{$1}}")`  but ya, why?

Comment: Why can't you write as `{{city}}`?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using some HTML preprocessor to replace `{{ }}` tags with proper JS values. Don't re-invent wheel. Does your VueJS work in this place?

Comment: @Ronak07 did you try looking up how to write regexes? This doesn't seem terribly complicated, I don't think you really need our help.

Comment: I can but suppose user write it as {{ city }} then my replace will not work

Comment: additionally you marked it as "vue.js".  which seems to indicate you are doing something you shouldn't

Comment: It seems like you want to be using [handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this snippet can help?

```js
const data = {
  name: 'Ari',
  age: 26,
  city: 'Tokyo'
};

const template = "Hello, my name is {{name}} and I'm {{ age}} years old and currently I'm living in {{ city }}.";

const replaced = template.replace(/{{\s*(\w+)\s*}}/g, (_, key) => data[key]);

console.log(replaced);
```

You can also check [here to see how replacer function works in `String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: `Maybe an explanation can help?`, Answers need to be explained, and not just code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about regex, this will match with whitespaces or not

```
'<p>{{ city }}</p>'.replace(/{{\s*city\s*}}/, 'mumbai')
```

The key thing is `\s*` witch matches zero or more whitespaces. The star is the quantifier and \s is whitespace. If you want zero or *one* whitespace, you can replace the star with a +